# Async method not calling

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

Calling the **`awaitMethod()`** doesn't print the the second call of the `console.printline` in `GetFilmCount()` nor does the last print statement in `awaitMethod()` gets called. 
The only output is the  `Console.printLine()` in the first call to GetFilmCount().

Am I doing something wrong here. Cant figure out why its behaving like this ??

```
public async void awaitMethod()
{
    int count1 = await GetFilmCount(1);
    int count2 = await GetFilmCount(2);

    Console.WriteLine("Number of films {0}, {1} ", count1,count2 );
}

public async Task<int> GetFilmCount(int count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Count {0} ", count);

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    { 
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select sleep(5) ; select count(*) from sakila.film", connection);

        return await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            return Convert.ToInt32(t.Result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `awaitMethod`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `async void` unless it's a UI event handler (which doesn't seem to be the case).

What probably happens here is that you're not waiting for `awaitMethod` to complete (you can't because it's a `void` method) and so your console application ends before the rest of your code has a chance to execute.

Use `async Task` instead and `await` (or call `Wait()` if it's in `Main`) the returned `Task`:

```
public async Task awaitMethod()
{
    int count1 = await GetFilmCount(1);
    int count2 = await GetFilmCount(2);

    Console.WriteLine("Number of films {0}, {1} ", count1,count2 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks changed it to call p.awaitMethod().Wait(); :)

Comment: @jtkSource just be aware that you should only do that when you are in the `Main` function, do that do that with a UI app or you will lock up your program. (I know it was mentioned in the answer but this mistake is made often enough I wanted to say it again)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - agree! Is there a actual need of async pattern ? cant the same be achieved with the existing library